# How to get started tuning ecus?

Tags: fuel-system, electronic-control-module, tuning

Now I plan on building my own vehicle soon , and I wanted to know where can I begin learning how to tune a vehicle’s ecu and the necessary programs required to tune ecus on top of the understanding behind efi and everything that tuning encompasses.I know about the 4 stroke combustion cycle, the 14.7 parts air to 1 part fuel mixture , how power is made through ignition of the air fuel mixture , I know very little about the process of actually tuning ecus ,what I think happens is , you actually buying a tunable ecu and upload(write) your engine management program on it and then play with some numbers(values) like more fuel in the air fuel mixture , ignition timing and ect to gain more power or whatever your goal is (this is all what I’ve gathered from research) And I want to be sure and I’m still unclear about the whole process And I’m really looking for an understanding of how to get started , a reference to understand the process and anything else that would help me along my journey

Comment: What do you know about the combustion cycle and effects of things like valve opening /  closing times?

Comment: I know about the 4 stroke combustion cycle, the 14.7 parts air to 1 part fuel mixture , how power is made through ignition of the air fuel mixture , I know very little about the process of actually tuning ecus ,what I think happens is , you actually buying a tunable ecu and upload(write) your engine management program on it and then play with some numbers(values) like more fuel in the air fuel mixture , ignition timing and ect to gain more power or whatever your goal is (this is all what I’ve gathered from research) And I want to be sure and I’m still unclear about the whole process

Comment: Then get an existing tuning expert to set it up for you - much quicker and less likely to get something wrong (mistake = blown engine...)

Comment: The plan is to be able to tune my own vehicles and have a deep understanding of tuning , I’m not worried about blowing my engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at [Megasquirt](http://megasquirt.info/) - it's a DIY ECU, and was designed from the start to allow people to learn about engine controls and how to adapt them.

From their website:

> MegaSquirt is all about education and learning – its very existence came about as an effort to understand engine controls, and how to adapt to a multitude of applications. So there is a vast sea of information available – no other project offers this much information and practical installation tips!
>
> Remember – Megasquirt does require calibration and tuning! To successfully install and tune the ECU you will need to understand engine operation and fuel injection methods. The more you understand the better your installation. The documentation provided should guide you through this process as well as giving you the opportunity to learn some of the underlying theory. Also the online forums at msefi.com and msextra.com offer thousands of individuals just like yourself who are willing to help and get you running.

Comment: Good shout! I'd forgotten about Megasquirt

Answer (score 1):

Your best starting point is probably to get a standalone mappable ECU such as an Emerald K6 or an Omex. These will come with a basic configuration to get you started and the appropriate software to interface with the ECU and map it.

> you actually buying a tunable ecu and upload(write) your engine management program on it and then play with some numbers(values) like more fuel in the air fuel mixture , ignition timing and ect to gain more power or whatever your goal is

Sort of - you don't have to write the engine management program though, you go straight to the "playing with numbers" stage. Actually learning what changes to make and to what numbers is non-trivial though - the ECU manufacturer will usually give you some documentation to get you started. A full tutorial on how to do so is way outside the scope of the site (and tbh my knowledge!) but hopefully this can at least give you some place to start.